# How to access json key value from ajax success?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, dictionary

I want to access the logs of the data I am getting from the ajax response. I want to create it as an array so that I can access all the logs. But right now whenever I parse the data, it takes it as a single object value.

In the data there is only one _id=1. I want to access the logs.

```
[
 {
   "_id": "1",
   "qos": "Access",
   "date": "2020-02-26",
   "logs": [
     {
       "qos": "Access",
       "date": "2020-02-26",
       "hour": 23,
       "cellName": "A11" 
     },
     {
       "qos": "Access",
       "date": "2020-02-26",
       "hour": 21,
       "cellName": "A12" 
     }
     {
        similar for entries
     },{}
}
]
```

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       async: 'false',
       url: '/data_from_datastore',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data: JSON.stringify(sendDate1),
       success: function (data) {
           debugger;

               data = JSON.parse(data); // Here I want to create an array of all the log values
```

I want to read the data as:

```
 [
     {
       "qos": "Access",
       "date": "2020-02-26",
       "hour": 23,
       "cellName": "A11" 
     },
     {
       "qos": "Access",
       "date": "2020-02-26",
       "hour": 21,
       "cellName": "A12" 
     }
     {
        similar for entries
     }
}
]
```

Is there any way to parse only the log part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can parse only the piece of data. But you can use array.reduce, like

```
const logs = data.reduce((result, item) => { return [...result, item.logs] }, []);
```

Or some not ECMA2015 version, like

```
var logs = [];
data.forEach(function(item){ logs.push(item.logs); });
```

Or if you need only the first item of the data array -

```
var logs = JSON.parse(data)[0].logs;
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```js
result = JSON.parse(data)[0].logs;
```